# debian systemd: ceph-osd@x.service: Failed at step LIMITS spawning /usr/lib/ceph/ceph-osd-prestart.sh: Operation not permitted

Tags: ansible, ceph, systemctl

The error appears in `/var/log/syslog` while creating new OSDs to a Ceph cluster. The symptoms are silent and ansible shows the following error:

```
    monclient: authenticate NOTE: no keyring found; disabled cephx 
authentication", "librados: client.admin authentication error (95)
 Operation not supported", " stderr: [errno 95] error connecting to the cluster"
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is with fixing the resource limit on the host.

- Find out the requested limits by the service.

`$ vim /lib/systemd/system/ceph-osd@.service`

- Check out the limits

  `[Service]
      LimitNOFILE=1048576
      LimitNPROC=1048576`
- Check the max limits of your system.

  `# ulimit -a
      core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
      data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
      scheduling priority             (-e) 0
      file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
      pending signals                 (-i) 148786
      max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
      max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
      open files                      (-n) 145383
      pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
      POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
      real-time priority              (-r) 0
      stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
      cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
      max user processes              (-u) 148786
      virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
      file locks                      (-x) unlimited`
- Set the limits expected by the host.

  `[Service]
      LimitNOFILE=145383
      LimitNPROC=148786`
- Reload systemctl daemon

  `$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
- Restart your service